# How to prevent rerender when using react functional components

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am exceeding my API uses due to the fact that everytime I change tabs on my site it makes a refreshes and makes all the API Calls over again. All the code provided is the component for the tabs, everything works properly just trying to prevent the refresh on tab switches. Is there any way to prevent this?

```
    import React, { useEffect, useState } from 'react';
    import PropTypes from 'prop-types';
    import { makeStyles } from '@material-ui/core/styles';
    import AppBar from '@material-ui/core/AppBar';
    import Tabs from '@material-ui/core/Tabs';
    import Tab from '@material-ui/core/Tab';
    import Typography from '@material-ui/core/Typography';
    import Box from '@material-ui/core/Box';
    import Container from '@material-ui/core/Container';

    import API from "../../utils/API"
    import Players from "../Players/index"


    function TabPanel(props) {
        const { children, value, index, ...other } = props;

        return (
            <div
                role="tabpanel"
                hidden={value !== index}
                id={`scrollable-force-tabpanel-${index}`}
                aria-labelledby={`scrollable-force-tab-${index}`}
                {...other}
            >
                {value === index && (
                    <Box p={3}>
                        <Typography>{children}</Typography>
                    </Box>
                )}
            </div>
        );
    }

    TabPanel.propTypes = {
        children: PropTypes.node,
        index: PropTypes.any.isRequired,
        value: PropTypes.any.isRequired,
    };

    function a11yProps(index) {
        return {
            id: `scrollable-force-tab-${index}`,
            'aria-controls': `scrollable-force-tabpanel-${index}`,
        };
    }

    const useStyles = makeStyles((theme) => ({
        root: {
            flexGrow: 1,
            width: '100%',
            backgroundColor: theme.palette.background.paper,
        },
    }));

    export default function TeamNav() {
        const classes = useStyles();
        const [value, setValue] = React.useState(0);
        const [teams, setTeams] = useState([])

        const handleChange = (event, newValue) => {
            setValue(newValue);
        };


        useEffect(() => {

            API.getAllTeams()
                .then(res => {
                    setTeams(res)
                })

        }, [])


        console.log(teams)
        return (
            <Container maxWidth="lg">
                <div className={classes.root}>
                    <AppBar position="static" color="default">
                        <Tabs
                            value={value}
                            onChange={handleChange}
                            variant="scrollable"
                            scrollButtons="on"
                            indicatorColor="primary"
                            textColor="primary"
                            aria-label="scrollable force tabs example"
                        >

                            <Tab label="Atlanta Hawks" icon={<img src={"https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/en/2/24/Atlanta_Hawks_logo.svg"} style={{ width: '70px', height: '70px' }} alt="ATL HAWKS"></img>} {...a11yProps(0)} />

                            <Tab label="Boston Celtics" icon={<img src={"https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/en/8/8f/Boston_Celtics.svg"} style={{ width: '70px', height: '70px' }} alt="BOSTON CELTICS"></img>} {...a11yProps(1)} />

                            <Tab label="Brooklyn Nets" icon={<img src={"https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/4/44/Brooklyn_Nets_newlogo.svg"} style={{ width: '70px', height: '70px' }} alt="BROOKLYN NETS"></img>} {...a11yProps(2)} />

                            <Tab label="Charlotte Hornets" icon={<img src={"https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/en/c/c4/Charlotte_Hornets_%282014%29.svg"} style={{ width: '70px', height: '70px' }} alt="CHARLOTTE HORNETS"></img>} {...a11yProps(3)} />

                            <Tab label="Chicago Bulls" icon={<img src={"https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/en/6/67/Chicago_Bulls_logo.svg"} style={{ width: '70px', height: '70px' }} alt="CHICAGO BULLS"></img>} {...a11yProps(4)} />

                            <Tab label="Cleveland Cavaliers" icon={<img src={"https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/en/4/4b/Cleveland_Cavaliers_logo.svg"} style={{ width: '70px', height: '70px' }} alt="CLEVELAND CAVALIERS"></img>} {...a11yProps(5)} />

                            <Tab label="Dallas Mavericks" icon={<img src={"https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/en/9/97/Dallas_Mavericks_logo.svg"} style={{ width: '70px', height: '70px' }} alt="DALLAS MAVERICKS"></img>} {...a11yProps(6)} />

                            <Tab label="Denver Nuggets" icon={<img src={"https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/en/7/76/Denver_Nuggets.svg"} style={{ width: '70px', height: '70px' }} alt="DENVER NUGGETS"></img>} {...a11yProps(7)} />

                            <Tab label="Detroit Pistons" icon={<img src={"https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/7/7c/Pistons_logo17.svg"} style={{ width: '70px', height: '70px' }} alt="DETROIT PISTONS"></img>} {...a11yProps(8)} />

                            <Tab label="Golden State Warriors" icon={<img src={"https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/en/0/01/Golden_State_Warriors_logo.svg"} style={{ width: '70px', height: '70px' }} alt="DETROIT PISTONS"></img>} {...a11yProps(9)} />

                            <Tab label="Houston Rockets" icon={<img src={"https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/en/2/28/Houston_Rockets.svg"} style={{ width: '70px', height: '70px' }} alt="HOUSTON ROCKETS"></img>} {...a11yProps(10)} />

                            <Tab label="Indiana Pacers" icon={<img src={"https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/en/1/1b/Indiana_Pacers.svg"} style={{ width: '70px', height: '70px' }} alt="INDIANA PACERS"></img>} {...a11yProps(11)} />

                            <Tab label="Los Angeles Clippers" icon={<img src={"https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/en/b/bb/Los_Angeles_Clippers_%282015%29.svg"} style={{ width: '70px', height: '70px' }} alt="LOS ANGELES CLIPPERS"></img>} {...a11yProps(12)} />

                            <Tab label="Los Angeles Lakers" icon={<img src={"https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/3/3c/Los_Angeles_Lakers_logo.svg"} style={{ width: '70px', height: '70px' }} alt="LOS ANGELES LAKERS"></img>} {...a11yProps(13)} />

                            <Tab label="Memphis Grizzlies" icon={<img src={"https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/en/f/f1/Memphis_Grizzlies.svg"} style={{ width: '70px', height: '70px' }} alt="MEMPHIS GRIZZLIES"></img>} {...a11yProps(14)} />

                            <Tab label="Miami Heat" icon={<img src={"https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/en/f/fb/Miami_Heat_logo.svg"} style={{ width: '70px', height: '70px' }} alt="MIAMI HEAT"></img>} {...a11yProps(15)} />

                            <Tab label="Milwaukee Bucks" icon={<img src={"https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/en/4/4a/Milwaukee_Bucks_logo.svg"} style={{ width: '70px', height: '70px' }} alt="MILWAUKEE BUCKS"></img>} {...a11yProps(16)} />

                            <Tab label="Minnesota Timberwolves" icon={<img src={"https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/en/c/c2/Minnesota_Timberwolves_logo.svg"} style={{ width: '70px', height: '70px' }} alt="MINNESOTA TIMBERWOLVES"></img>} {...a11yProps(17)} />

                            <Tab label="New Orleans Pelicans" icon={<img src={"https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/en/0/0d/New_Orleans_Pelicans_logo.svg"} style={{ width: '70px', height: '70px' }} alt="NEW ORLEANS PELICANS"></img>} {...a11yProps(18)} />

                            <Tab label="New York Knicks" icon={<img src={"https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/en/2/25/New_York_Knicks_logo.svg"} style={{ width: '70px', height: '70px' }} alt="NEW YORK KNICKS"></img>} {...a11yProps(19)} />

                            <Tab label="Oklahoma City Thunder" icon={<img src={"https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/en/5/5d/Oklahoma_City_Thunder.svg"} style={{ width: '70px', height: '70px' }} alt="OLKAHOMA CITY THUNDER"></img>} {...a11yProps(20)} />

                            <Tab label="Orlando Magic" icon={<img src={"https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/en/1/10/Orlando_Magic_logo.svg"} style={{ width: '70px', height: '70px' }} alt="ORLANDO MAGIC"></img>} {...a11yProps(21)} />

                            <Tab label="Philidelphia 76ers" icon={<img src={"https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/en/0/0e/Philadelphia_76ers_logo.svg"} style={{ width: '70px', height: '70px' }} alt="PHILIDELPHIA 76ERS"></img>} {...a11yProps(22)} />

                            <Tab label="Phoenix Suns" icon={<img src={"https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/en/d/dc/Phoenix_Suns_logo.svg"} style={{ width: '70px', height: '70px' }} alt="PHOENIX SUNS"></img>} {...a11yProps(23)} />

                            <Tab label="Portland Trailblazers" icon={<img src={"https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/en/2/21/Portland_Trail_Blazers_logo.svg"} style={{ width: '70px', height: '70px' }} alt="PORTLAND TRAILBLAZERS"></img>} {...a11yProps(24)} />

                            <Tab label="Sacramento Kings" icon={<img src={"https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/en/c/c7/SacramentoKings.svg"} style={{ width: '70px', height: '70px' }} alt="SACRAMENTO KINGS"></img>} {...a11yProps(25)} />

                            <Tab label="San Antonio Spurs" icon={<img src={"https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/en/a/a2/San_Antonio_Spurs.svg"} style={{ width: '70px', height: '70px' }} alt="SAN ANTONIO SPURS"></img>} {...a11yProps(26)} />

                            <Tab label="Toronto Raptors" icon={<img src={"https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/en/3/36/Toronto_Raptors_logo.svg"} style={{ width: '70px', height: '70px' }} alt="TORONTO RAPTORS"></img>} {...a11yProps(27)} />

                            <Tab label="Utah Jazz" icon={<img src={"https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/en/0/04/Utah_Jazz_logo_%282016%29.svg"} style={{ width: '70px', height: '70px' }} alt="UTAH JAZZ"></img>} {...a11yProps(28)} />

                            <Tab label="Washinton Wizards" icon={<img src={"https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/en/0/02/Washington_Wizards_logo.svg"} style={{ width: '70px', height: '70px' }}></img>} {...a11yProps(29)} />

                        </Tabs>
                    </AppBar>
                    <TabPanel value={value} index={0}>
                        <Players team="ATL"></Players>
                    </TabPanel>
                    <TabPanel value={value} index={1}>
                        <Players team="BOS"></Players>
                    </TabPanel>
                    <TabPanel value={value} index={2}>
                        <Players team="BKN"></Players>
                    </TabPanel>
                    <TabPanel value={value} index={3}>
                        <Players team="CHA"></Players>
                    </TabPanel>
                    <TabPanel value={value} index={4}>
                        <Players team="CHI"></Players>
                    </TabPanel>
                    <TabPanel value={value} index={5}>
                        <Players team="CLE"></Players>
                    </TabPanel>
                    <TabPanel value={value} index={6}>
                        <Players team="DAL"></Players>
                    </TabPanel>
                    <TabPanel value={value} index={7}>
                        <Players team="DEN"></Players>
                    </TabPanel>
                    <TabPanel value={value} index={8}>
                        <Players team="DET"></Players>
                    </TabPanel>
                    <TabPanel value={value} index={9}>
                        <Players team="GS"></Players>
                    </TabPanel>
                    <TabPanel value={value} index={10}>
                        <Players team="HOU"></Players>
                    </TabPanel>
                    <TabPanel value={value} index={11}>
                        <Players team="IND"></Players>
                    </TabPanel>
                    <TabPanel value={value} index={12}>
                        <Players team="LAC"></Players>
                    </TabPanel>
                    <TabPanel value={value} index={13}>
                        <Players team="LAL"></Players>
                    </TabPanel>
                    <TabPanel value={value} index={14}>
                        <Players team="MEM"></Players>
                    </TabPanel>
                    <TabPanel value={value} index={15}>
                        <Players team="MIA"></Players>
                    </TabPanel>
                    <TabPanel value={value} index={16}>
                        <Players team="MIL"></Players>
                    </TabPanel>
                    <TabPanel value={value} index={17}>
                        <Players team="MIN"></Players>
                    </TabPanel>
                    <TabPanel value={value} index={18}>
                        <Players team="NO"></Players>
                    </TabPanel>
                    <TabPanel value={value} index={19}>
                        <Players team="NY"></Players>
                    </TabPanel>
                    <TabPanel value={value} index={20}>
                        <Players team="OKC"></Players>
                    </TabPanel>
                    <TabPanel value={value} index={21}>
                        <Players team="ORL"></Players>
                    </TabPanel>
                    <TabPanel value={value} index={22}>
                        <Players team="PHI"></Players>
                    </TabPanel>
                    <TabPanel value={value} index={23}>
                        <Players team="PHO"></Players>
                    </TabPanel>
                    <TabPanel value={value} index={24}>
                        <Players team="POR"></Players>
                    </TabPanel>
                    <TabPanel value={value} index={25}>
                        <Players team="SAC"></Players>
                    </TabPanel>
                    <TabPanel value={value} index={26}>
                        <Players team="SA"></Players>
                    </TabPanel>
                    <TabPanel value={value} index={27}>
                        <Players team="TOR"></Players>
                    </TabPanel>
                    <TabPanel value={value} index={28}>
                        <Players team="UTA"></Players>
                    </TabPanel>
                    <TabPanel value={value} index={29}>
                        <Players team="WAS"></Players>
                    </TabPanel>
                </div>
            </Container>
        );
    }
```

Comment: When *do* you want to call the api?

Comment: it looks like you are updating state in `handleChange` called in the `onChange` of  `<Tabs /> ` component, which would trigger a re-render as React re-renders when state is updated. You could maybe find a hook that is equivalent of `componentShouldUpdate` and do something with that

Comment: Do you mean the `API.getAllTeams` ? or something else that isinside the `Players` component ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could create another component (e.g. `<TeamNavWithData>`) that does the API call and renders `<TeamNav>` passing the teams as props to `<TeamNav>`. Changing the active tab inside `<TeamNav>` would then still re-render `<TeamNav>` but not `<TeamNavWithData>` and hence not call the API.

Comment: I don't really understand what you mean. So creating a new component called <TeamNavWithData> which renders <TeamNav props=teams>?

Comment: Exactly, that's what I was suggesting.